# SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryLifeRemaining returns -1?

Tags: .net, vb.net, power-management, system-information

In my code I have:

```
Dim ps as PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
Dim batteryTimeLeft as Integer = ps.BatteryLifeRemaining 'I have a problem here

MsgBox("Time left on battery: " & cstr(batteryTimeLeft),vbInformation,"Info")
```

`PowerStatus.BatteryLifeRemaining` always returns -1 when I have a battery present and used or when not used. Why does this always return -1?

I currently am using MS .NET 4.0 Client Profile on VB.NET 2010 Express. I unplug the for my laptop and see if it makes a difference and it doesn't. Also tried in plugged in.

Help please???

**EDIT:** Never mind now I can't get the `PowerStatus.BatteryFullLifetime` to return other than -1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test your application on a Desktop machine with no battery? If yes that may be the reason why you get -1 since it is not applicable.

Can you instead try running you application on  a laptop?